# How to refresh Cookies using okhttp3?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

The REST API I connect to uses `cookie-based` authorization. Basically, issuing a call, I get a `cookie`, which then I use in all my requests. That `cookie` has an expiry time on the Server side. Once `cookie` expired, I get notified, I have to acquire a new `cookie` to proceed.
To achieve this, I am using `OkHttp3 client`, to which I attached a `PersistentCookieJar`. Somewhere in between, I also have an `Interceptor` that catches the `session expired` responses, and tries to renew the `cookie`. After my `Interceptor` does the call to renew the `cookie`, it `re-tries` the previously failed call. Which, **fails again**. I suppose it is because the retry of the call is done with **old cookie**.

**Any suggestions**?

Some code snippets below:

```
//OkHttp client with the interceptor and the cookiejar
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

builder.addInterceptor(sessionExpiryInterceptor);
    if (cache != null) {
      builder.cache(cache);
    }

return builder
       .cookieJar(cookieJar)
       .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .build();
```

The `PersistentCookieJar` is used as described here: https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar

And last, the `Interceptor:`

```
public class SessionExpiryInterceptor implements Interceptor {

  @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    final Request request = chain.request();
    final Response response = chain.proceed(request);
    //analyze to see if it is "session expired"
    String bodyString = response.body().string();
    Response copyResponse = copyResponse(response, bodyString);

    //attempt to parse the original body
    if (isRefreshRequired(bodyString)) {
      //we send the response copy from here on out, as the original no longer as a "body" - extracted and parsed earlier
      return refreshData(request, copyResponse, chain);
    } else {
      //return the copy since body was extracted earlier
      return copyResponse;
    }
  }

    private boolean isRefreshRequired(String responseBody) throws IOException {
    //does some parsing of the responseBody to extract a "status" and "message"
    return status == RESPONSE_CODE_NO_SESSION || message.contains("session");
  }

    private Response refreshData(Request request, Response responseCopy, Chain chain) throws IOException {
    //does some checks before attempting to actually refresh the cookie, 
     mAuthService.login(user, pass)
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
              .observeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
              .subscribe(createLoginSubscriber());
    if (mDataRefreshed) {
      // rebuild the request with the new acquired cookie
      Request retry = createRetryRequest(request);
      return chain.proceed(retry);// !!! this call fails again - I get "session expired" response message.
    } else {
      //for whatever reason the refresh failed - send back the original response's copy 
      return responseCopy;
    }
  }

    private Subscriber<LoginResponse> createLoginSubscriber() {
    return new Subscriber<LoginResponse>() {

      @Override public void onCompleted() {
      }

      @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
        LOG.e(e, "login failed" + e.getMessage());
      }

      @Override public void onNext(LoginResponse response) {
        if(response.isSuccess()) {
          mDataRefreshed = true;
        } else {
          mDataRefreshed = false;
          //some cleanup code here
        }
      }
    };
  }

    private Request createRetryRequest(Request source) {
    //I suspect this copy might be the issue?
    return source.newBuilder().build();
  }

    //copies the given response rewriting the body with the given one with character set UTF-8
  private Response copyResponse(Response original, String body) {
    return original.newBuilder()
            .body(new RealResponseBody(original.headers(), new Buffer().writeUtf8(body)))
            .build();
  }
}
```